# AWS Systems Manager Event for Hybrid Activation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I am using AWS Systems Manager to manage some on-prem [Hybrid Activation] servers.  When a server is registered with SSM and joins the fleet I want some actions to be taken (tags added, SSM docs run, etc ...). But I cannot find any documentation on any events generated by SSM when this occurs.  Unsure if "Association State Change" fits the bill or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently AWS Systems Manager does not generate any events for this occurrence. Hopefully they will add it in the future.